# Writing and testing python code using existing OSGeo4W Python3 install?

Tags: python-3, idle

Looking for a development environment, like idle, for Python 3.6.1 that I can install and use with my existing python3 installation from the OSGeo4W. I am trying to learn python for use with QGIS and don't want multiple python installs of various versions confusing me and my work environments.

How should I set myself up for best results?

Comment: Why not just use IDLE?  As far as I know it comes with every Python install.  I use it with Python 3.6 and ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Any decent IDE will allow you to choose an existing Python environment.  [PyCharm is my preferred one](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) and is leaps and bounds ahead of IDLE in terms of its feature set

Comment: Maybe I don't know how to use it then; I tried Idle but when I use import commands it couldn't find any of the modules I installed in the OSGeo python. How do I point it to the python I want to use?
In a nutshell I am trying to migrate plugins I use a lot from QGIS2 to 3